# Running Coded UI TestMethod that loops through multiple pages

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

I have a `TestMethod` that will loop through all pages that contain a certain user control on them. The issue I'm running into is that when/if my assertion fails I'm not able to see the page it failed on in the error message or stack trace.  Is there a way to customize or add in additional parameters to be shown in the test results details?

Not that it's really needed, but here's my code...

```
[TestMethod]
public void uiTestCourseListingPages() {
    UiBrowserWindow uiBrowserWindow = new UiBrowserWindow();
    string controlType = "~/_control/course/courseList.ascx";
    var request = WebRequest.Create(Utility.GET_PAGES_WITH_CONTROL_URL + controlType);
    request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";

    using(var response = request.GetResponse()) {
        using(var streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())) {
            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            List<PagesWithControl> pagesWithControl = serializer.Deserialize<List<PagesWithControl>>(streamReader.ReadToEnd());
            pagesWithControl.ForEach(x => {
                // launch browser
                uiBrowserWindow.launchUrl(x.key);
                // setup assertions
                Assert.AreEqual(
                     uiBrowserWindow.uiHtmlDocument.searchHtmlElementByAttributeValues<HtmlDiv>(new Dictionary<string, string> {
                        {HtmlDiv.PropertyNames.Class, "footer"}
                    }).Class,
                    "footer"
                );
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an overloaded Assert.AreEqual(object,object,string). If you put the URL into the string that would show up in the test results.

Answer (score 0):

When a `CodedUI Test` fails it keeps an image of the desktop when the failure occurs. You can check if an error image is created.

It is by default created inside the `TestResults` folder which is by default located inside your `Project` folder. If your tests are running as a part of your `Team Build` or through `MTM` you can change the default TestResults path by editing the Test Settings:

- [How to: Edit a Test Settings File from Microsoft Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404693.aspx)
- [How to: Edit an Existing Test Setting for a Test Plan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd535596.aspx)

Comment: I have never had any luck with getting meaningful test result images from those. It seems like MTM or VS always block any useful information.

Comment: Well, indeed. It is supposed to mark as red the area where a control was not found or an assertion had failed but you're right, there are not always work as expected. But in case where you are accessing many pages it will be helpful or wasted disk space :).

Answer (score 0):

The best way to log errors are to try..catch them. Then add them to a string, then at the end of the test assert if the string is not empty.

This way to can provide more detail to the errors, location etc.

The video below explains how:

Robust code, continue on errors
http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/showcase/details.aspx?uuid=65967d59-798b-47ce-9743-534d1c106657